file opener 2 is not working with api level 34 (Android 14)
I am trying to open a pdf file just after downloading it via cordova file transfer plugin. Even after downloading it and passing the exact same path in fileOpener2.open function, i am getting file not found. It does not matter where the file is being stored i just want the file to be displayed just after the download button click.
i tried using every cordova.file.* to set a path for download and use the same path to open but i am getting the same error since. If fileopener2 is not convenient i am okay to use another plugin just to open a downloaded pdf file. I know about the scoped storage stuff in new androids and fileopener2 is not maintained now but i want something to work as the task is extremely simple but due to lack of knowledge in android dev, i am unable to achieve this for the past 2 weeks. I want for both android and ios.
Below is my current code
function downloadFile() {
// Remote URL of the PDF file
var fileUrl =
"";
      // Local filesystem URL where the file will be saved
      var targetPath =
        cordova.file.externalApplicationStorageDirectory +
        "CRS_Form" +
        ".pdf"; // You can change the target path as needed

      // Check if the FileTransfer plugin is available
      if (typeof FileTransfer !== "undefined") {
        // Initialize the File Transfer Plugin
        var fileTransfer = new FileTransfer();

        // Define the options for the download
        var options = {
          trustAllHosts: true, // Set this to true if you're using a self-signed SSL certificate
        };

        // Start the download
        fileTransfer.download(
          fileUrl,
          targetPath,
          function (entry) {
            // Success callback
            console.log("Download success! File saved to: " + entry.toURL());
            // You can perform additional actions here after successful download
            cordova.plugins.fileOpener2.open(targetPath, "application/pdf", {
              error: function (e) {
                console.log(
                  "Error status: " +
                    e.status +
                    " - Error message: " +
                    e.message
                );
              },
              success: function () {
                console.log("file opened successfully");
              },
            });
          },
          function (error) {
            // Error callback
            console.error("Download error: " + JSON.stringify(error));
          },
          options
        );
      } else {
        // Handle the case when the FileTransfer plugin is not available
        console.error("FileTransfer plugin not available.");
      }
    }

getting error: file not found in the line
cordova.plugins.fileOpener2.open(targetPath, "application/pdf", {
error: function (e)

I assume you use this project: https://github.com/pwlin/cordova-plugin-file-opener2 - Next time please read the readme: Due to signficant changes in the way that Android handles permissions from version 11 onwards, this plugin does not work with Android 11 or later and would require significant changes to make this happen.
